# Given multiple two columns sets of a min/max how to return index if a number falls between min/max

Tags: python, pandas

My input CSV looks like this

```
Tier    | A   |     | B   |     | C   |   
        | Min | Max | Min | Max | Min | Max
1       | 0   | .5  | 0   | .25 | 0   | .92
2       |.51  | 1.0 | .26 | .50 | .93 | 1.5
```

Given an input dictionary `{A: .56, B: .22, C: .99}` I want to return `{A: 2, B: 1, C: 2}`, the tiers corresponding to where the number is within the range.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to read the header into a multi-index, or even if its worth bothering.

Currently what I've tried is zipping the columns every other and then turning those into one column tuples, storing the tuples under every set of min/max per "A B C" set.  I'm also thinking about just going  down the max column and finding the first tier which the number is under.

But these don't seem like the best way to do this, any tips?

Comment: is your input csv ingested as a list of dicts or nested dicts/json?

Comment: Currently it's just ingested as a dataframe, where the blank spaces are NaN.  My current solution is to store each min/max as a tuple, then store the tuples in a dictionary under their category.  Then to pull the tier, I iterate through each category, then each tuple until the number falls between the two, then return a tier based on a counter.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the first couple rows. You can use the kwarg `header=[0,1]` to read the first two rows as a `MultiIndex` but the missing values in level 0 cause placeholder names to be used (in the columns that don't have an 'A', 'B', or 'C'.

See the `read_csv` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more details about the args/kwargs.

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep=' *\| *', skiprows=2, index_col=0, header=None)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B', 'C'), ('Min', 'Max')])

def get_indicator(letter, val, df):
    m = (df[letter]['Min'] <= val) & (df[letter]['Max'] >= val)
    m = m[m]
    return None if m.empty else m.index[0]

d = {A: .56, B: .22, C: .99}

res = {k: get_indicator(k, v, df) for (k, v) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this setup:

```
arrays = [[0, .5, 0, .25, 0, .92,],[.51,1, .26, .5, .93, 1.5, ]]
col    = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B', 'C'), ('Min', 'Max')])
df     = pd.DataFrame(arrays, columns=col )

     A          B           C      
    Min  Max   Min   Max   Min   Max
0  0.00  0.5  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.92
1  0.51  1.0  0.26  0.50  0.93  1.50


dd     = {'A':.56,'B':.22, 'C':.99}
```

Try This:

```
ddOut = {}
for k,v in dd.iteritems():
    if   v <= df[(k, "Max")][0]                          : ddOut[k] = 1
    elif v >= df[(k, "Max")][0] and v < df[(k, "Max")][1]: ddOut[k] = 2

print ddOut
{'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}
```